# Detect if chrome is webview?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-app, browser-detection

Is there a way of detecting if content was accessed by stand alone Chrome or within a webview (from a chrome app) ? E.g.

```
if(chromeapp) {
  //content is in a webview / chromeapp
} else {
  //all other browsers
}
```

Can be jQuery too...

Edit: I'm developing a chrome-app which is connected to a content managed website. In a global js file, I need to return different values depending on where it is being accessed from.

If desktop return this...
If iOS return this...
If android etc...
If chrome app...

It is a packaged app that embeds the content as `<webview>`.

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "...",
  "short_name": "...",
  "description": "...",
  "version": "...",
  "minimum_chrome_version": "38",
  "default_locale": "en",
  "icons": {
    "16": "...",
    "128": "...",
    "192": "...",
    "256": "...",
    "384": "...",
    "512": "..."
  },
  "app": {
    "background": {
      "scripts": ["background.js"]
    }
  },
  "permissions": [
    "<all_urls>",
    "storage",
    "system.memory",
    "system.network",
    "unlimitedStorage",
    {"fileSystem": ["write", "retainEntries", "directory"]},
    "webview",
    "downloads",
    "fullscreen"
   ],
   "webview" : {
     "partitions": [{
      "name" : "trusted*",
      "accessible_resources": ["<all_urls>"]
     }]
   },
   "sockets": {
    "tcpServer" : {
      "listen": ["*"]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain your scenario better? A hosted app? Embedded inside `<webview>`? Is the app under your control? Do you mean "Chrome browser" by saying "Chrome app"? Why do you need this?

Comment: @Xan Sorry. See edit.

Comment: So what kind of app you have? A [hosted app](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/get_started_simple) for the site? Or a [packaged app](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/about_apps) that somehow shares JavaScript? Or a packaged app that embeds the site [as `<webview>`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/webview)? Or a [Progressive Web App](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/your-first-progressive-web-app/)? Perhaps if you add your app manifest it will be helpful.

Comment: Question updated. Forgive me but I'm not sure what is confusing with the question: _Is the navigator chrome or chrome within a chrome-app?_

Comment: The confusing part is that "within a chrome app" can mean about 5 different things. Now the question is clear ("within a `<webview>` tag").

Answer (score 2):

If the webapp is under your control it would be best to change the useragent of the webapp or pass a variable in the url so that your site knows it's accessed through the webapp.

For example: http://ww.mywebsite.com/?app=webview

Comment: Possible solution. But I may need to change content with this solution so it might be a no-go.

Comment: I've used the user-agent solution for my own webbased game's android app. If the site detects a normal browser you get a notification telling you there's an app, if the site detects the app user-agent then you get forwarded to the game. As far as I know that was then (about 2 years ago) the best solution.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest you can do is override User-Agent for your `<webview>`.

```
// App window code
webviewElement.setUserAgentOverride(
  navigator.userAgent + " HeyItsMyApp/" + chrome.runtime.getManifest().version
);
webviewElement.src = "https://example.com"; // Initiate navigation

// webpage code
if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("HeyItsMyApp") >= 0) {
  // It's embedded in our app
}
```

---

Alternatively, you can test for a known file inside your app thanks to `accessible_resources` (which you currently misuse, as it's not a list of match patterns for the webview content, but a list of patterns for files inside your extension). For example, assuming `hello.txt` is in your extension:

```
"webview" : {
  "partitions": [{
    "name" : "trusted*",
    "accessible_resources": ["hello.txt"]
   }]
 },
```

Then in your webpage you can try loading `chrome-extension://youridhere/hello.txt` - it will only succeed within your app.

This may be a more tamper-proof solution, though nothing is completely tamper-proof.

---

Alternatively still, you can inject a content script that is meant to inform the page that it's embedded, perhaps by adding some invisible DOM element.

Comment: Good idea but I can't seem to be able to set the agent. Not getting any errors and I'm setting this on **createdWindow**

Comment: You'll need to show code (separate question?) but consider that to use my code your webview should have it `src` initially unset.

Comment: I see.. I will need to get back to this later today.

Comment: I could not get this to work. Although, it would of been much better to be able to this, I ended up passing a variable via the app.

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScript function below works for me. If you want to test on iOS you can install https://apps.apple.com/fr/app/satisfi-labs-webview-tester/id1556211591. On Android you can use https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.snc.test.webview2&hl=nl&gl=US

```
function isWebView() {
        var expressions = [
            // if it says it's a webview, let's go with that
            'WebView',
            // iOS webview will be the same as safari but missing "Safari"
            // webview test on iPad 2022/07/07 showed "Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 15_5 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/15e148)"
            // Safari test on iPad 2022/07/07 showed "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_6) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/15.5 Safari/605.1.15"
            // Chrome test on iPad 2022/07/07 showed "Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 15_5 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) CriOS/103.0.5060.63 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1
            '(iPhone|iPod|iPad)(?!.*Safari)',
            // Android Lollipop and Above: webview will be the same as native but it will contain "wv"
            // Android KitKat to lollipop webview will put {version}.0.0.0 !!!! NOT SUPPORTED BY THIS REGEX
            // webview test on Android phone 2022/07/07 showed "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux;Android 11;moto g 5G plus Build/RPNS31.Q4U-39-27-9-2-8;wv) AppleWebKit/537.36(KHTML, like Gecko) version/4.0 Chrome/103.0.5060.70 Mobile Safari/537.36 WEBVIEW TEST/1.3.1.106 (Phone;anonymlous)"
            // Chrome test on Android phone 2022/07/07 showd "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux;Android 11;moto g 5G plus) AppleWebKit/537.36(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36"
            'Android.*(;wv)',
            // old chrome android webview agent
            'Linux; U; Android'
        ];

        var userAgent = window.navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase()
        var webviewRegExp = new RegExp('(' + expressions.join('|') + ')', 'ig');

        return !!userAgent.match(webviewRegExp);
    }
```